# Express doesn't support data-method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, html, express

I learned Rails and know in HTML:

`<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log out</a>`

...Rails can receive "Delete" method. Now I use node and express in this way, but the web server receive "Get" method.

What does rails do to support **data-method="delete"**, and how to make express support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works using rails because Rails adds a js file which catches events on links with this kind of properties, then triggers the appropriate requests with the adapted verb.

[See here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/c50b05ab46a655a32c0ee348576d2465e183f9de/src/rails.js#L180).

I guess you could took this js file, just ensure you have jQuery and it doesnt interfere with your own scripts.

---

Besides, Rails contains a middleware which checks `_method` params and changes the http verb according to it.

You can have the same behavior in express using [method-override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) and `app.use(methodOverride('_method'))`

Comment: Is this js file  a standalone library like jquery?

Comment: I tried as you told, now it works, but the req method is "POST", not "Delete" , Is the anything else I need to do? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is handled in JQuery, the specific function it uses is this -

```
// Handles "data-method" on links such as:
// <a href="/users/5" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
handleMethod: function(link) {
  var href = rails.href(link),
    method = link.data('method'),
    target = link.attr('target'),
    csrfToken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
    csrfParam = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content'),
    form = $('<form method="post" action="' + href + '"></form>'),
    metadataInput = '<input name="_method" value="' + method + '" type="hidden" />';

  if (csrfParam !== undefined && csrfToken !== undefined) {
    metadataInput += '<input name="' + csrfParam + '" value="' + csrfToken + '" type="hidden" />';
  }

  if (target) { form.attr('target', target); }

  form.hide().append(metadataInput).appendTo('body');
  form.submit();
},
```

Comment: In my layout I included JQuery                                                              <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Make sure you have jquery and jquery_ujs

Comment: problem is it relies on stuff present in rails like `meta[name=csrf-token]` and `meta[name=csrf-param]` not sure its a good idea to take it as is.

Comment: Right, if you're using this on a page not created by rails those won't be there, and including jquery_ujs may not work because of how it is built around rails. You may be able to get by just removing those parts of the function, and calling this method when the link is clicked.

Comment: I include this file in html, it works, but the req method changed to "POST", not "Delete", as @apneadiving and you told, using this file directly may be not a good idea.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, there are only truly GET and POST, but things like DELETE are POST with a hidden input called `_method` with a value `delete` that says it should be DELETE.